# Mac OS X 10.10 merge tool git bugs

Tags: macos, git

When I am attempting to use git mergetool I get the following errors.

```
Normal merge conflict for 'application/language/dutch/config_lang.php':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff): 
2014-10-16 16:30:02.996 FileMerge[42541:5140761] Failed to connect (delegate) outlet from (DiffController) to (DiffController): missing setter or instance variable
2014-10-16 16:30:02.997 FileMerge[42541:5140761] Failed to connect (mainPrefPane) outlet from (DiffController) to (NSBox): missing setter or instance variable
2014-10-16 16:30:03.071 FileMerge[42541:5140761] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
2014-10-16 16:30:03.072 FileMerge[42541:5140761] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
```

What can I do to fix this? The tool launches but I cannot continue after the first file.

NOTE: This error is intermittent, but happens most of the time.

Comment: Have you tried different mergetools?

Comment: I have this same issue after upgrading to OS X El Capitan and XCode 7.0 and 7.1. I'm using opendiff as part of the Mercurial brew package. I have not found a fix for the "Failed to connect" messages.

Answer (score 18):

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms

plutil -convert xml1 iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist

plutil -convert xml1 iPhoneSimulator.platform/Info.plist
```

This fixes the 2nd set of warnings. This has been an issue since 10.8,
but apple ignores my bug report :)

Comment: With the latest XCode release, I found I also had to run plutil on AppleTVOS, AppleTVSimulator, WatchOS, and WatchSimulator plist files.

Comment: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms; for w in {iPhoneOS,iPhoneSimulator,AppleTVOS,AppleTVSimulator,WatchOS,WatchSimulator}; do sudo plutil -convert xml1 $w.platform/Info.plist ; done`

Answer (score 3):

I see the same behavior after upgrading from 10.9. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200103) answer, delete both iPhoneOS.platform and iPhoneSimulator.platform. Or reinstall them properly from XCode if you need them. The former worked for me.